# Creating Google Sheets pivot tables with custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

I am creating table for finance: will have a data base of trades: date open and close for trade (), open and close prices, ticket is a stock name, change is percentage which is calculated base on open-close price and days are also calculated base on two dates as on the picture:

[image]

And I need to generate a new table for each month of the year (in which I have date records). So, Google sheets has Pivot tables and that what I need. I need columns: average win % per month, average loss % per month, average number of win days per month, average number of loss days per month.

I did that in 2 separate tables:

First table:

[image]

First table settings:

[image]

Second table:

[image]

Second table settings:

[image]

But I can not create that in one table - I do not know how to make custom formula. So, I am looking for some help here.

I tried some things, I can filter, make average. But I do not know how to get array of items with sorted pivot table data by months...If I can get sorted pivot table data by months - I can filter by positive/negative and find average.

My sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TCLWZ7-oUSwM8DLODPpH6wwssgfYyo3BVlEpWj78kV4/edit?usp=sharing